# Spring Boot Data Initialization getting exception

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot

In my setup i have `datasource.initialization` set to always.

**Problem**

`spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create` This works as designed every time I start up the application or make a change to application it re-creates the DB and then inserts data from `data.sql`

But when I change from `create` to `update` I get MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException.  Update means that it only start doing work if Hibernate detects a change right?  Then why am I getting duplicate entry?

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#configurations-hbmddl

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '10001' for key 'PRIMARY'
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:936) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3976) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3912) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2530) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2683) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2482) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2440) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:845) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:745) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:95) ~[HikariCP-2.7.8.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-2.7.8.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:473) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    ... 73 common frames omitted
```

Application.properties

```
## DB confige
....

## Hibernate Properties
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect


# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, validate, update)
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create  ###### <---- Problem
```

data.sql

```
insert into course (id, name, created_date, last_updated_date)
values(10001, 'JPA in 50 steps', NOW(), NOW()),
        (10002, 'Spring', NOW(), NOW()),
        (10003, 'Spring Boot', NOW(), NOW());

insert into review(id, description, rating, course_id)
values(50001, 'Okey course', '3', 10001),
        (50002, 'Awesome course', '5', 10001),
        (50003, 'Greate Course', '4', 10003);

insert into passport(id, number)
values(40001, 'ASD2342324'),
        (40002, 'NMWO23423'),
        (40003, 'POOI9098473');


insert into student(id, name, passport_id)
values(20001, 'Ranga', 40001),
        (20002, 'Adam', 40002),
        (20003, 'Jane', 40003);

insert into student_course(student_id, course_id)
values(20001,10001),
(20002,10001),
(20003,10001),
(20001,10003);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is 
`spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create` will drop database and recreate everytime you start your application.

While `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update` will fire query to update your database based on entity changes without dropping it or any data inside.

So with update and your `data.sql` that is always run, it's obviously going to insert rows that are already there.

As a quick-fix you can set `spring.datasource.continue-on-error` property and ignore the `data.sql` failure.

But it might be worth learning to use `Flyway` or `Liquibase` as suggested in the docs as they are much more robust then the `ddl-auto = update`.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html

Comment: Okey... so update it doesn't check if there are any changes. it just re-initialize database with data.sql?.... Humm looking back on the doc I thought I read somewhere it says hibernate will compare and if there are changes it will update

Comment: But before spring 2.x the same scenario worked fine without exception.